# SSH Remote host identification has changed error tried deleting known_hosts

Tags: linux, ssh, dns, openwrt, verification

I tried using **ssh-keygen -R**  but it gave some error. I tried to ssh to my router using the ssh command, then it asks for the password but I couldn't log in as it gives permission denied. However, when I try using sudo, it again gives the old error of **WARNING: POSSIBLE  DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!** and **Remote host identification has changed**.
I saw a number of similar issues but most of them get solved by the above command. What's the way to resolve it? Any help is appreciated.[ssh command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ecXp.png) [verbose output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtYZu.png)
***strong text***

Comment: Update: I am able to ssh into the router using putty from windows, but am not able to ssh into the router from ubuntu, Terminal. I have no idea why. Any suggestions?